# Uchar equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c++, unsigned-char

I want to convert some C++ code to Java and I need Java equivalent of `uchar` to use the below C++ code.

```
cvSetReal2D(output, x, y, CV_MAT_ELEM(input, uchar, y, x));
```

Comment: Byte?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html

Comment: In Java, you always deal with Unicode. You can use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: And what is `CV_MAT_ELEM()` supposed to do?